# Can we take infima over an infinite sum?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A_1, A_2,...,A_n,...$ infinitely many sets of numbers that are all bounded below (so the infimum of each one exists). Suppose $\alpha$ is a number such that  we have for all $a_j\in A_j$ ($j=1,2,...$)
$$\alpha\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j. $$
Can we take now the infima of $a_j$ over the set $A_j$ for all $j=1,2,...$ and write:
$$\alpha\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \inf\{a: a\in A_j\}? $$
It seems to me that since the sum is infinit, there must be a problem to do so(???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, you can pick $a_j\in A_j$ such that $a_j<\inf A_j+2^{-j}\epsilon$.